# Show the uniqueness of the polynomial $p(x)$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots

> Let $p(x)$ such that $\deg(p) \le 2n+1$ and $$p(x_i) = f(x_i) \\ p'(x_i) = f'(x_i)$$ $i=0,\ldots, n$.
>   Show that $p(x)$ is the only polynomial satisfying those demands for all polynomials with a degree $\le 2n+1$.
>   **Assumption:** for every $j\ne k$: $x_j \ne x_k$.

So let's assume by contradiction that there's another polynomial, $q(x)$ satisfying those constraints.

I'm not sure why but I think we would like to assume WLOG that $p(x),q(x)$ are monic.

Anyways, let's look at $h(x) = p(x) - q(x)$.

We notice that for $x_i$:$$h(x_i) = p(x_i) - q(x_i) = f(x_i) - f(x_i) = 0$$

So $h(x)$ has at least $n$ roots, and therefore, $h'(x)$ has at least $n-1$ roots .

My goal is to show that $h(x)\equiv 0$ by showing that there're more than $2n$ roots (I think $\deg(h(x)$ should be $\le 2n$ since we looked at monic polynomials)

How should I proceed?

**EDIT**
Basically, the same applies for the derivative:

$$h'(x_i) = p'(x_i) - q'(x_i) = 0$$

but aren't those the same roots as before?

Comment: You may need additional constraints for the claim to hold. For example, the $x_i$ better be distinct. And, no, you cannot assume monic

Comment: Alright. I'll add the the distinct constraint to my question (maybe it was omitted but was the intention of the author)

Comment: WLOG assume $x_1<x_2<...<x_n$. Then, $h(x_1)=0, h(x_2)=0$ so Rolle's theorem tells us that $h'(x)=0$ for some $x_1<x<x_2$. Similarly, we can say this for $x_i<x_{i+1}$ and so we have $n+1+n=2n+1$ roots to $h'(x)=0$. So $h$ would have degree $2n+2$ ot higher. Contradiction.

Comment: @daruma, how did you get $2n+1$? I'm missing it..

Comment: $n+1$ from $x_0, x_1, ....,x_n$ and then $n$ from the Rolle's theorem

Comment: right.... ! Cheers :)

Comment: Between each interval $(x_i, x_{i+1})$ , there is a root to $h'(x)=0$ by Rolle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wlog. $x_0<x_1<\ldots <x_n$.
From $h(x_k)=h(x_{k+1})\,(=0)$, we see that there are numbers $\xi_k$ with $x_k<\xi_k<x_{k+1}$ and $h'(\xi_k)=0$ (Rolle's theorem).
Thus we know that $h'$ has $2n+1$ distinct roots $x_0<\xi_0<x_1<\xi_1<\ldots <x_n$.
Uisng $\deg h\le\max\{\deg p,\deg q\}\le 2n+1$, we have $\deg h'\le 2n$ and hence conclude $h'\equiv 0$. That makes $h$ constant. As $h(x_0)=0$, $h\equiv 0$.